# predicateWithSubstitutionVariables always throws exception

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array of objects using predicateWithSubstitutionVariables, this code throws an exception

```
NSPredicate *pSample = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS [c] $variable"];
[pSample predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"variable":@"sample string"}];
NSLog(@"%@", [mArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pSample]);
```

**Exception I get:**

```
reason: 'Can't get value for 'variable' in bindings {
}.
```

Why can't I use this ? (I'm not looking for an alternative solution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code like,

```
NSPredicate *pSample = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS [c] $variable"];
NSPredicate *actualPredicate = [pSample predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"variable":@"sample string"}];
NSLog(@"%@", [mArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: actualPredicate]);
```

First predicate you created `pSample` is the template used to create actual predicate. `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables` gives the actual predicate you need.